# help getting output from perl dbi code

Tags: perl

I am learning how to use perl with dbi for oracle. I am simply trying to test getting output, but I am unable to print out the result from this simple select.

I would appreciate if someone can help me figure this out or even show me a better way to write this. Thanks.

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;
use Time::localtime;
use POSIX qw/uname/;

use vars qw/$dbh $scr $computer_name/;
$scr = basename($0, '');
$computer_name = (uname())[1];

 $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:testdb', 'test', 'test', 
                    {RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0}) ||
       die "$scr: connect error on $computer_name [$DBI::errstr]";

my $out = get_val();
print "The date is $out\n";
$dbh->disconnect;

sub get_val
{
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
        SELECT sysdate 
        FROM   dual}) ||
      die "$scr: prepare error on $computer_name [$DBI::errstr]";
  $sth->execute;
  my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
  $sth->finish;
  return $row->{VALUE};
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in the hash returned by fetchrow_hashref are the column names.  You're getting the key 'VALUE' from the returned hashref, which isn't a column in your query.

Comment: thanks, its even case sensitive. It had to be upper case.  I had to put `SYSDATE`

Answer (score 0):

fetchrow_hashref() returns each column as a key in the hash.  The return statement should be:

```
return $row->{sysdate};
```